# Laravel 5.3, Class cant be found, While the route is correct

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am currently working on [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers):

The problem right now that i have, The route that im calling inside the ComposerServiceProvider.php says that it cant find the route to the ViewComposers/LespakketComposer.php

In the Config\app.php i did add the correct App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,

Here is my code in ComposerServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        View::composer('*','App\Http\ViewComposer\LespakketComposer');

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Here is my error:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class App\Http\ViewComposer\LespakketComposer does not exist
```

[The Routes in my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb9Mr.png)

Does anyone has a solution for my problem?
( The file i am requesting is an **Class** Indeed )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a `s`:

```
App\Http\ViewComposers\LespakketComposer
```

Comment: Need more coffee then, Thanks Alot

Comment: @StijnKluiters no worries, please mark my answer as right if I helped you, thanks